# How to resolve the usage of the Gfx dev memory

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-leaks, adb

I am using `adb shell dumpsys meminfo` to get informations about the current memory usage of my app.
The Gfx dev memory increases frequently and seems to cause memory leaks.

**Is there an adb command or and Android Studio function to get more informations about the Gfx dev memory and where it is used/referenced?**

```
                   Pss  Private  Private  Swapped     Heap     Heap     Heap
                 Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
                ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
  Native Heap    17380    17324        0        0    36864    19380    17483
  Dalvik Heap    30366    29796        0        0    50519    48334     2185
 Dalvik Other      672      672        0        0
        Stack      220      220        0        0
      Gfx dev     4704     4704        0        0
    Other dev        5        0        4        0
     .so mmap     2109      356      872        0
    .jar mmap        1        0        0        0
    .apk mmap      707        0      420        0
    .ttf mmap       35        0        4        0
    .dex mmap     7442        0     7400        0
    .oat mmap     2712        0      948        0
    .art mmap     1458      948       72        0
   Other mmap       42        4        0        0
   EGL mtrack    13888    13888        0        0
    GL mtrack     8924     8924        0        0
      Unknown      172      172        0        0
        TOTAL    90837    77008     9720        0    87383    67714    19668
```

**Additional Info:**

Gfx dev is not available for Kitkat devices and below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below command to get more info on Gfx;

```
adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo
```